# Remove old toe touch bathtub drain stopper with no screw

Tags: plumbing, drain

I have an old toe touch bathtub drain stopper that is stuck in the closed position and doesn't stop the water escaping either. I want to remove the stopper.

I removed the cap the cap by pulling on it and expected to see a slot for a flathead on the rod the cap fits on. But mine doesn't have one, what you see in the photo is a bump.

I tried twisting and pulling the rod hard with channel locks but it didn't move.

The cap says "RAPIDFIT" on the bottom of it. Here's the [patent info](http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&d=PALL&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsrchnum.htm&r=1&f=G&l=50&s1=4420844.PN.&OS=PN/4420844&RS=PN/4420844) found from the number on the cap.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Rapid Fit threads in, as do almost all "toe touch" tub stoppers.

Yours is broken, that's why you only see the upper part of the threaded stem. Soak with penetrating oil and unscrew. Replacements can be found at a good local plumbing shop, or online.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I think you have to remove the whole fitting.

[image]

Notice that [frequently bought together](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000I1E9TY) with toe touch drain stoppers is a Tub Drain Extractor:

[image]

([source](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00C0M7DVA))

Comment: So you think the drain and stopper are one piece?

Comment: @user193661 - I've never had to deal with one. I'm assuming it is. If you want to put a new one in, like the one pictured, I'd think you'd have to, considering someone would have to identify yours for you to even know what parts to get. Which is not out of the question, so you might want to wait for more advice.

Comment: Speak of the devil, everyone upvote @Jimmy's answer, who knows enough about these things to say yours is broken.